# rake routes fails because of "missing action"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started a clean rails app, installed and migrated the devise gem as well as a couple straightforward models of my own.  The devise user controller methods are not working (I get an error page when I go to localhost:3000/users/new but not when I got to /users/sign_up).  When I run rake --trace routes, I get the following output:

(in /Users/tim/Coding/rails_projects/libertyhive)
** Invoke routes (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
missing :action
/Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:167:in `default_controller_and_action'

/Users/tim/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:68:in `normalize_options!'

and it continues with many more lines of /Users/tim/.rvm/gem/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/gems/...

I have no idea how to debug this.  I'm pretty new to rails.  Did the Rails 3 Tutorial by Michael Hartl, which helped me through most of the general setup and configuration of rails.

Any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails uses a RESTful interface by default for routing URLs.  That means there is no action called :sign_up.

The user signup URLs would be:

1. the form to add a new user:  http://localhost:3000/users/new (a GET request)
2. when you submit the form for a new user:  http://localhost:3000/users ( a POST request)

Comment: ok, thanks.  I'm not sure why I had root pointed to "sign_up" in my routes.rb file.  That was dumb.  Unclear to me how you knew that though.  Maybe just a coincidence?  Because /users/sign_up does work, that's the route devise gives for sign up.